# Two modal windows from yui example

Tags: javascript, yui

I would like to have two buttons to open each one a diferent modal window with diferente content.

I am using this example from yui: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/panel/panel-form-example.html

Things i try that did not work:
1. trying to duplicate the code 
1. trying to duplicate the code and naming each div with a diferent name . Eg.: 
Add and Add 1

and

This is the code from the example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?3.12.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css&amp;3.12.0/build/cssfonts/fonts-min.css&amp;3.12.0/build/cssbase/base-min.css">
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.12.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
<div id="dt"></div>
<p><button id="addRow">Add</button></p>
<div id="panelContent">
    <div class="yui3-widget-bd">

    </div>
</div>

<div id="nestedPanel"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
YUI().use('datatable-mutable', 'panel', 'dd-plugin', function (Y) {

    // Create the datatable with some gadget information.
    var idField    = Y.one('#productId'),
        nameField  = Y.one('#name'),
        priceField = Y.one('#price'),
        addRowBtn  = Y.one('#addRow'),

        cols = ['id', 'name', 'price'],
        data = [
            {id:'ga-3475', name:'gadget', price:'$6.99'},
            {id:'sp-9980', name:'sprocket', price:'$3.75'},
            {id:'wi-0650', name:'widget', price:'$4.25'}
        ],

        dt, panel, nestedPanel;

    // Define the addItem function - this will be called when 'Add Item' is
    // pressed on the modal form.
    function addItem() {
        dt.addRow({
            id   : idField.get('value'),
            name : nameField.get('value'),
            price: priceField.get('value')
        });

        idField.set('value', '');
        nameField.set('value', '');
        priceField.set('value', '');

        panel.hide();
    }

    // Create the main modal form.
    panel = new Y.Panel({
        srcNode      : '#panelContent',
        headerContent: 'Add A New Product',
        width        : 250,
        zIndex       : 5,
        centered     : true,
        modal        : true,
        visible      : false,
        render       : true,
        plugins      : [Y.Plugin.Drag]
    });


    // When the addRowBtn is pressed, show the modal form.
    addRowBtn.on('click', function (e) {
        panel.show();
    });

});

</script>
```

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just work out in an example wich works :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="yui3-loading">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Using a panel to show a modal form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?3.12.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css&amp;3.12.0/build/cssfonts/fonts-min.css&amp;3.12.0/build/cssbase/base-min.css">
        <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.12.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body class="yui3-skin-sam">

        <style type="text/css">
            #desc {
                margin-bottom: 20px;
                border-bottom: 1px dotted #333;
            }
            #desc span {
                background: #a3350d;
                padding :2px;
                color:# f27243;
            }

            .yui3-panel {
                outline: none;
            }
            .yui3-panel-content .yui3-widget-hd {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            .yui3-panel-content .yui3-widget-bd {
                padding: 15px;
            }
            .yui3-panel-content label {
                margin-right: 30px;
            }
            .yui3-panel-content fieldset {
                border: none;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .yui3-panel-content input[type="text"] {
                border: none;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                padding: 3px 7px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
                -moz-border-radius: 2px;
                border-radius: 2px;
                font-size: 100%;
                width: 200px;
            }

            #addRow {
                margin-top: 10px;
            }

            #dt {
                margin-left: 1em;
            }

            #dt th, #dt td {
                border: 0 none;
                border-left: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
            }
        </style>

        <h2>Using a panel to show a modal form</h2>

        <div class="yui3-u-1">

            <div id="dt"></div>

            <p><button id="addRow">Add 1</button></p>
            <p><button id="addRow2">Add 2</button></p>

            <div id="panelContent">
                <div class="yui3-widget-bd">
                    <form>
                        <fieldset>
                            <p>
                                <label for="id">ID</label><br/>
                                <input type="text" name="id" id="productId" placeholder="">
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label for="name">Name</label><br/>
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="">
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label for="password">Price</label><br/>
                                <input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="" placeholder="$">
                            </p>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="nestedPanel"></div>

            <p></p>

            <div id="panelContent2">
                <div class="yui3-widget-bd">
                    <form>
                        <fieldset>
                            <p>
                                <label for="id">ID</label><br/>
                                <input type="text" name="id" id="productId" placeholder="">
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label for="name">Name</label><br/>
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="">
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label for="password">Price</label><br/>
                                <input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="" placeholder="$">
                            </p>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="nestedPanel2"></div>

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            YUI().use('datatable-mutable', 'panel', 'dd-plugin', function (Y) {

                // Create the datatable with some gadget information.
                var idField    = Y.one('#productId'),
                    nameField  = Y.one('#name'),
                    priceField = Y.one('#price'),
                    addRowBtn  = Y.one('#addRow'),
                    addRowBtn2  = Y.one('#addRow2'),

                    cols = ['id', 'name', 'price'],
                    data = [
                        {id:'ga-3475', name:'gadget', price:'$6.99'},
                        {id:'sp-9980', name:'sprocket', price:'$3.75'},
                        {id:'wi-0650', name:'widget', price:'$4.25'}
                    ],

                    dt, panel, nestedPanel;

                // Define the addItem function - this will be called when 'Add Item' is
                // pressed on the modal form.
                function addItem() {
                    dt.addRow({
                        id   : idField.get('value'),
                        name : nameField.get('value'),
                        price: priceField.get('value')
                    });

                    idField.set('value', '');
                    nameField.set('value', '');
                    priceField.set('value', '');

                    panel.hide();
                }

                // Define the removeItems function - this will be called when
                // 'Remove All Items' is pressed on the modal form and is confirmed 'yes'
                // by the nested panel.
                function removeItems() {
                    dt.data.reset();
                    panel.hide();
                }

                // Instantiate the nested panel if it doesn't exist, otherwise just show it.
                function removeAllItemsConfirm() {
                    if (nestedPanel) {
                        return nestedPanel.show();
                    }

                    nestedPanel = new Y.Panel({
                        bodyContent: 'Are you sure you want to remove all items?',
                        width      : 400,
                        zIndex     : 6,
                        centered   : true,
                        modal      : true,
                        render     : '#nestedPanel',
                        buttons: [
                            {
                                value  : 'Yes',
                                section: Y.WidgetStdMod.FOOTER,
                                action : function (e) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    nestedPanel.hide();
                                    panel.hide();
                                    removeItems();
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                value  : 'No',
                                section: Y.WidgetStdMod.FOOTER,
                                action : function (e) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    nestedPanel.hide();
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                }

                // Create the DataTable.
                dt = new Y.DataTable({
                    columns: cols,
                    data   : data,
                    summary: 'Price sheet for inventory parts',
                    caption: 'Price sheet for inventory parts',
                    render : '#dt'
                });

                // Create the main modal form.
                panel = new Y.Panel({
                    srcNode      : '#panelContent',
                    headerContent: 'Add A New Product',
                    width        : 250,
                    zIndex       : 5,
                    centered     : true,
                    modal        : true,
                    visible      : false,
                    render       : true,
                    plugins      : [Y.Plugin.Drag]
                });

                panel.addButton({
                    value  : 'Add Item',
                    section: Y.WidgetStdMod.FOOTER,
                    action : function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        addItem();
                    }
                });

                panel.addButton({
                    value  : 'Remove All Items',
                    section: Y.WidgetStdMod.FOOTER,
                    action : function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        removeAllItemsConfirm();
                    }
                });

                // When the addRowBtn is pressed, show the modal form.
                addRowBtn.on('click', function (e) {
                    panel.show();
                });

                //custom

                // Create the main modal form.
                panel2 = new Y.Panel({
                    srcNode      : '#panelContent2',
                    headerContent: 'Add A New New Product',
                    width        : 250,
                    zIndex       : 5,
                    centered     : true,
                    modal        : true,
                    visible      : false,
                    render       : true,
                    plugins      : [Y.Plugin.Drag]
                });

                // When the addRowBtn is pressed, show the modal form.
                addRowBtn2.on('click', function (e) {
                    panel2.show();
                });

            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```